# How to center Item inside Surface in jetpack compose

Tags: android, center, android-jetpack-compose, surface

How to center item inside the surface in jet pack compose

```
@Composable
fun RoundedShapeWithIconCenter(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    parentSize : Dp,
    parentBackgroundColor : Color,
    childPadding : Dp,
    icon : Painter,
    iconSize : Dp,
    iconTint : Color,
    elevation : Dp = 0.dp,
    isTextOrIcon : Boolean = false,
    insideText : String = "",
    insideTextColor : Color = colorResource(id = R.color.black),
    fontSize: TextUnit = 16.sp
) {
    Surface(
        modifier = modifier.size(parentSize),
        shape = RoundedCornerShape(50),
        color = parentBackgroundColor,
        elevation = elevation,
    ) {
        if (isTextOrIcon) {
            CommonText(value = insideText, fontSize = fontSize, color = insideTextColor, textAlign = TextAlign.Center)
        } else {
            Icon(painter = icon, contentDescription = "Back Arrow", modifier = Modifier
                .size(iconSize)
                .padding(childPadding), tint = iconTint)
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

In image the circular black color shape is Surface and Go is Text inside Surface. I want to center the Go text inside the Surface. If I replace text with icon it center perfectly

Thanks in advance

Comment: can you share CommonText composable cause i have bit of confusion about it.

Comment: ```@Composable
fun CommonText(value : String, fontSize : TextUnit, color : Color, modifier : Modifier = Modifier, fontWeight: FontWeight = FontWeight.Normal, textAlign: TextAlign = TextAlign.Left) {
    Text(text = value, fontSize = fontSize, color = color, modifier = modifier)
}

Comment: Thanks, i have added an easier version which doesn't require to add modifier to Text as Box also provide contentAlignment parameter.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

for this we have align our Text composable to the centre, and we can't use align modifier inside Surface. so we will wrap our CommonText around Box and make a little change to CommonText that accept modifier.

**RoundedShapeWithIconCenter**

```
....
if (isTextOrIcon) {
    Box(modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxSize(1.0f) // it will fill parent box
        .padding(8.dp)) { // padding will help us to give some margin between our text and parent if text greater then our parent size

            CommonText(
                value = insideText, 
                fontSize = fontSize, 
                color = insideTextColor,
                modifier = Modifier.align(Alignment.Center) // this will help it to align it to box center
            )
        }
}
....
```

**Modified CommonText**

> as i don't know how CommonText Composable is created i assume it like following and make changes according to it.

```
@Composable
fun CommonText(modifier: Modifier = Modifier, .... ) {
    Text(modifier = modifier, .... )
}
```

#### Edit - easier version

```
....
if (isTextOrIcon) {
    Box(modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxSize(1.0f) // it will fill parent box
        .padding(8.dp),// padding will help us to give some margin between our text and parent if text greater then our parent size
        contentAlignment = Center) { // contentAlignment will align its content as provided Alignment in our case it's Center

            CommonText(
                value = insideText, 
                fontSize = fontSize, 
                color = insideTextColor
            )
        }
}
....
```